# Solo mining requirement to win a block everyday?

Tags: mining-profitability, hashpower

What's the hash power requirements to solo mine and win at least one block a day?

Two cases (with 10% luck, means mining requires to iterate 90% of unsuccessful hashes),

1. Mine 24 hours a day and win at least one block
2. Mine 10 - 30 mins and win at least one block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is assuming the difficulty has balanced with the current network hash rate (right now, the difficulty is actually about 10% low, but it will adjust in about 3 days):

Network hash rate (current) = 61 Thash/s

Blocks per day = 24 * 6 = 144

Hash power required to solve 1 block per day = 61 Thash/s / 144 = 424 Ghash/s

To get a block on average every 30 minutes, you'd need control of one third of the network's hashpower, which (unless you purchase mining equipment already in use) would require 50% of the current hashpower, or 30.5 Thash/s.

To solve a block on average every 10 minutes is only possible if you control the entire network, which you can't do unless you stop everybody else from mining.

More info available here: [Equation for mining profit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8568/equation-for-mining-profit)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I have 424 GHash mining power, and solo mine for 24 hours a day, is it possible, still I win nothing?

Comment: @vi.su. Yes, and it doesn't increase the chances of you solving a block the next day either. However, it's also possible to solve many blocks within the same day. This answer has some info that may be relevant to you: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3911/516

Answer (score 3):

You can mine 1 block roughly every 10 mins, hence total blocks per day is 6 x 24 = 144

The current Hash Rate in the Network is about 70000 GH/sec (Source: Blockchain.info][1](http://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate)

If you have 100% of the Hash power, you will get all the blocks each day.

To get at least one block a day, you will need roughly 0.7% of the current total hash power (1/144), that is about 486 GH/sec of hash power.

To get at least one coin a day, you will need at least 19.44GH/sec of hash power ( 486 / 25 coins per block)

The hash power requirement will change as the network hash rate rises with more ASIC devices shipped.